# How to use Vue set with vuex 4.0

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex4

I've searched the documentation but can't find anywhere how to incorporate Vue to the vuex store in version 4.0

I am currently using vue 3 and vuex 4.0, the application starts here and is like this.

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";

import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./routes.js";
import store from "./store/index.js";

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(router);
app.use(store);

app.mount("#app");
```

I need the set function to update the object property in an array of objects from the store in this mutation method:

```js
updateSongFavorite(state, { songId, val }) {
    const index = state.songs.findIndex((song) => song.id === songId);
    if (index !== -1) {
      const song = { ...state.songs[index] };
      song.isFavorite = val;
      // Vue.set(state.songs, index, song); <-- This not works because Vue is not defined
    }
  },
```

I would hope to find some way to use it in this version of vuex or a different way of doing it.

Comment: You don't need to use `Vue.set` or clone `song`. Just set `isFavorite` directly, and it will be reactive: `state.songs[index].isFavorite = val`

Comment: @tony19 setting the value directly not works. The list change but vue not update the dom. I'm using getters like `computed: {...mapGetters({songs: "song/allSongs"})}` and in the first render this works, but after setting the value nothing happens.

Comment: Can you link to a reproduction?

Comment: The complete project is: [app](https://github.com/Jibaru/drive-music-player/tree/main/app), the file that contains the mutation is: `app/src/store/modules/song/mutations.js` and i render the list of songs on `app/src/components/song/SongList.vue`

Comment: @tony19 i solved the problem.The problem was in the way the data is updated. The list was updated correctly but when rendering a component that in turn had another component, the latter was not able to listen changes (since the list was not being rendered again). The solution was to place a watch on the `isFavorite` attribute in the component that rendered each item in the v-for.